# Why is this JS code working most places but not on my machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iife, function-constructor

I wrote some code which works fine in the Node env provided by repl.it (https://repl.it/repls/LimpingCharmingGravity), in the code snippet here (see below), and on codepen.io (https://codepen.io/tjfwalker/pen/OERXry?editors=0012#0). It's not working, however, with Node on my machine. Trying to run in produces the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: Entity is not defined
    at Entity.eval [as addSub] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/…pathtofile…/app.js:18:69), <anonymous>:3:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/…pathtofile…/app.js:60:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

My local node is 10.4.0 via nvm on macOS... though, I imagine it's not about that.

What gives?

```js
let activeUserMock = 'someUserName'

const Entity = (function() {
    let lastID     = 0
      , entityList = []
    
    function Entity(userFields, userMethods) {
        this.meta = {id: ++lastID, dob: new Date, creator: activeUserMock}
        
        userFields.forEach(
            function(field) {
                this[field.key] = field.value
            }
        ,this)
        
        userMethods.forEach(
            function(method) {
                this[method.name] = Function(...method.args, method.body)
            }
        ,this)
        
        entityList.push(this)
    }
    
    Entity.findByID = function(id) {
        return entityList.find(function(entity) {
            return entity.meta.id === id
        })
    }
    
    return Entity
})();

// ======= SIMULATE AN END USER —FROM SOME CLIENT UI— MODELING THEIR OWN DOMAIN ==========

new Entity([ //stuff from the user ↴
    {key: 'type', value: 'feature'}
   ,{key: 'name', value: 'LMS'}
   ,{key: 'subs', value: []}
   ,{key: 'sups', value: []}
   ,{key: 'desc', value: 'a module to facilitate learning.'}
],[
    {name: 'addSub', args: ['subID'], body: 'let sub = Entity.findByID(subID); this.subs.push(sub); sub.sups.push(this); return this'}
   ,{name: 'addSup', args: ['supID'], body: 'let sup = Entity.findByID(supID); this.sups.push(sup); sup.subs.push(this); return this'}
])

new Entity([ //stuff from the user ↴
    {key: 'type', value: 'feature'}
   ,{key: 'name', value: 'SRS'}
   ,{key: 'subs', value: []}
   ,{key: 'sups', value: []}
   ,{key: 'desc', value: 'a module that implements the spaced repetition learning technique.'}
],[
    {name: 'addSub', args: ['subID'], body: 'let sub = Entity.findByID(subID); this.subs.push(sub); sub.sups.push(this); return this'}
   ,{name: 'addSup', args: ['supID'], body: 'let sup = Entity.findByID(supID); this.sups.push(sup); sup.subs.push(this); return this'}
])

Entity.findByID(1).addSub(2)

// ==========================================================

console.log(Entity.findByID(1))
```

Comment: how are you running the code?

Comment: @J.Pichardo `node app.js` from the same dir as that file

Comment: On the surface, it seems to me that this question is going to require some more details, like your environment (what's running your js? what version is it?)

Comment: Yeah I agree with @CollinD

Comment: @J.Pichardo & @CollingD it's not about the node version, is just that `Function` only have access to the global scope, and in any node version, modules are not on the global scope, unless you're using `global.someVar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `eval()`, `Function()` constructor does not have access to the calling scope, it only have access to the global scope.

That script will fail in node, because every module has it's own scope, and `Entity` is not on the global namespace.

To check this, just wrap your code inside an IIFEE, and you will see that it will fail on the browser too. (See snippet below)

To "fix" your code in node, you will need to do:

```
global.Entity = (function() {
 /* ... */
})():
```

But you should probably rethink your approach, and use `bind` instead, and access `Entity` using `this`.

The following will fail in the browser too:

```js
(function() {
  let activeUserMock = 'someUserName'

  const Entity = (function() {
      let lastID     = 0
        , entityList = []

      function Entity(userFields, userMethods) {
          this.meta = {id: ++lastID, dob: new Date, creator: activeUserMock}

          userFields.forEach(
              function(field) {
                  this[field.key] = field.value
              }
          ,this)

          userMethods.forEach(
              function(method) {
                  this[method.name] = Function(...method.args, method.body)
              }
          ,this)

          entityList.push(this)
      }

      Entity.findByID = function(id) {
          return entityList.find(function(entity) {
              return entity.meta.id === id
          })
      }

      return Entity
  })();

  // ======= SIMULATE AN END USER —FROM SOME CLIENT UI— MODELING THEIR OWN DOMAIN ==========

  new Entity([ //stuff from the user ↴
      {key: 'type', value: 'feature'}
     ,{key: 'name', value: 'LMS'}
     ,{key: 'subs', value: []}
     ,{key: 'sups', value: []}
     ,{key: 'desc', value: 'a module to facilitate learning.'}
  ],[
      {name: 'addSub', args: ['subID'], body: 'let sub = Entity.findByID(subID); this.subs.push(sub); sub.sups.push(this); return this'}
     ,{name: 'addSup', args: ['supID'], body: 'let sup = Entity.findByID(supID); this.sups.push(sup); sup.subs.push(this); return this'}
  ])

  new Entity([ //stuff from the user ↴
      {key: 'type', value: 'feature'}
     ,{key: 'name', value: 'SRS'}
     ,{key: 'subs', value: []}
     ,{key: 'sups', value: []}
     ,{key: 'desc', value: 'a module that implements the spaced repetition learning technique.'}
  ],[
      {name: 'addSub', args: ['subID'], body: 'let sub = Entity.findByID(subID); this.subs.push(sub); sub.sups.push(this); return this'}
     ,{name: 'addSup', args: ['supID'], body: 'let sup = Entity.findByID(supID); this.sups.push(sup); sup.subs.push(this); return this'}
  ])

  Entity.findByID(1).addSub(2)

  // ==========================================================

  console.log(Entity.findByID(1))
})();
```

**UPDATE**

> what concretely does code look like that follows your recommendation
>   to "use bind instead, and access Entity using this

```
this[method.name] = Function(...method.args, method.body).bind(this)
```

And then use:

```
body: 'let sub = this.constructor.findByID(subID) ...'
```

Instead of:

```
body: 'let sub = Entity.findByID(subID) ...'
```

Comment: Given that your response is accurate, can you help me understanding why the code seems to be working as-is in other environments, e.g. the node env of the repl.it I linked to?

Comment: He kind of already has explained why, it's to do with scope.. Repl is not a module, so you have access to global scope again.   Your `app.js` is a module..

Comment: So, Marcos, what concretely does code look like that follows your recommendation to "use `bind` instead, and access `Entity` using `this`"?